Required changes to AppDelegate.mm for using aws-amplify push notifications (AWS Pinpoint) with React Native 0.74
I'm using aws-amplify push notifications and made all required changed to my AppDelegate.mm as described here: https://docs.amplify.aws/react-native/build-a-backend/push-notifications/set-up-push-notifications/. With this setup, push notifications where working with React Native < 0.74.
React Native 0.74 introduced some breaking changes and requires editing the AppDelegate.mm as generally described here: https://reactnative.dev/blog/2024/04/22/release-0.74#api-changes-to-pushnotificationios-deprecated
I'm having problems understanding:

Will aws-amplify push notifications work with React Native 0.74 out of the box? Or will this require aws-amplify to first update its modules?
What changes are required to my existing AppDelegate.mm to make this working (having currently implemented the instructions from the AWS Amplify documentation).

Thank you.
